# How to use Angular ngAfterViewInit with BehaviorSubject and creating Bing Map instances

Tags: angular, rxjs, bing

[Stackblitz - full code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bing-maps?embed=1&file=src/app/services/site-conditions.service.ts)

I have an Angular service which delivers lat/lon coordinates (BehaviorSubject asObservable) which is used by my BingMapComponent to initialize the map's center view (instance method setView). I create the instance of the map in ngAfterViewInit, and then create the subscription to the initial value and set the view in the subscription.

When I have BehaviorSubject default to null, the map instance view is set properly when the service eventually returns the initial coordinate values. However, when I default the BehaviorSubject to lat/lon coordinates, the map view does not get set to these coordinates.

What is the proper way of working with these lifecycles? The desired behavior is to have the Bing map view set to a default value a BehaviorSubject may provide.

```
@Injectable()
export class SiteConditionsService {
  // _center = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>(null); // works
  _center = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([41.49871231510167, -72.95581850473526]); // doesn't work

  center$ = this._center.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.getInitialCenter(0).subscribe(initialCenter => {
      this._center.next(initialCenter);
    })
  }

  getInitialCenter(reportId): Observable<number[]> {
    // would come from HTTP service
    const center = [41.49871231510167, -72.95581850473526];
    return from<number[]>([center]).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
}
```

and

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bing-map',
  templateUrl: 'bing-map.component.html',
  styles: [``]
})
export class BingMapComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  @ViewChild('streetsideMap') streetsideMapViewChild: ElementRef;

  streetsideMap: Microsoft.Maps.Map;

  constructor(private service: SiteConditionsService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createStreetSideMap();

    this.service.center$.pipe(
      filter(coords => !!coords),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(coords => {
      const [lat, lon] = coords;
      const position = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lon);
      this.streetsideMap.setView({ center: position }) // SETTING VIEW HERE
    });
  }

  createStreetSideMap() {
    this.streetsideMap = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
      this.streetsideMapViewChild.nativeElement,
      {
        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.streetside,
        streetsideOptions: {
          overviewMapMode: Microsoft.Maps.OverviewMapMode.hidden,
          showExitButton: false
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It have to work. Maybe it will work when you use the right credentials? Did you see the message on map?

Comment: The credentials aren't the issue. I did it with my credentials on my own computer but it still doesn't work. I just removed the credentials for the Stackblitz example so it's not public.